# AzureRM Multiple Providers breaking

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I'm not sure if I am doing something incorrectly, but I'm trying to use multiple providers[ with an alias + subscription so that I can use a keyvault in a different sub]

Simplifying things.

---

A slight update. I removed any complexity and did the following in a simple main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.93.1"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "=3.1.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}


provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  alias           = "kvaccess"
  subscription_id = "subforkvaccess"
  features {}
}


data "azurerm_key_vault" "this" {
  provider            = azurerm.kvaccess
  name                = "kvname"
  resource_group_name = "kvresourcegroup"
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
  name         = "test"
  value        = "test"
  provider     = azurerm.kvaccess
}
```

The secret is created and then it times out with the following error:

```
2022-03-18T19:45:54.921-0400 [ERROR] vertex "azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret" error: Provider produced inconsistent result after apply
╷
│ Error: Provider produced inconsistent result after apply
│
│ When applying changes to azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret, provider "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"].kvaccess" produced an unexpected new value: Root resource was present, but now
│ absent.
│
│ This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own issue tracker.
```

There are no sub modules or anything fancy. Just a main TF trying to create a secret locally. Am I doing something incorrect here?

Comment: Could be because you have a dot in ` alias.`.

Comment: That was from copy and pasting the code, that isn't there, sorry!

Comment: Is there by any chance a state file there? With only providers? Also, have you run `terraform init`? Would you mind posting the directory structure so we can see what calls what?

Comment: I'm going to edit my original post for the viewability

Comment: Would you try adding the aliased provider config to the module's `main.tf`?

Comment: Marko, thanks for replying. I moved into troubleshooting into a much simpler form. I'll edit my main post again. Thanks again.

Comment: There was a [bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10371) before but that appeared to be fixed.  What happens when you run `terraform apply` once again after failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in my environment is working fine. Use the below terraform code which I have make changes in yours.

1. You were missing to create resource group or if you want to use your existing resource group use data source
2. Make Sure You hit **terraform init** before **terraform apply**

**Terraform Code:**

> ```
>         terraform {
>         required_version = ">= 0.13.0"
>         required_providers {
>         azurerm = {
>         source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
>         version = "=2.93.1"
>         }
>         random = {
>         source  = "hashicorp/random"
>         version = "=3.1.0"
>         }
>         }
>         }
>         provider "azurerm" {
>         
>         features {}
>         skip_provider_registration = true
>         }
>         provider "azurerm" {
>         skip_provider_registration = true
>         alias  = "kvaccess"
>         subscription_id = "b83XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-b5ba-2b83"
>         features {}
>         }
>         data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
>         name = "v-XXXXXXdtree"
>         }
>         data "azurerm_key_vault" "this" {
>         provider  = azurerm.kvaccess
>         name  = "kvname342"
>         resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
>         }
>         resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
>         key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
>         name  = "test"
>         value  = "test"
>         provider  = azurerm.kvaccess
>         }
> ```

[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to answer + reply here. I'm not sure what changed - the code is the same, and it works now. Multiple providers feels like it gets very odd.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing bug [11059](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11059) opened with Hashicorp.

It has been discussed as a sporadic issue which cannot be replicated always & something related to ARM caches going out of sync.

Below workaround steps were discussed:

1. Catch this exact error
2. Add tag with any value (like test:test) to KeyVault resource
3. Run terraform import command to import explicitly existing secrets which already exist, and which terraform can't obtain during apply phase.
4. Execute apply again and it will pass

Though this seem to be highly unlikely to implemented in your automations, but I see no other workaround than the above one discussed there.

Disclaimer :: I couldn't manage to replicate with various scenarios. Hence, sharing as-is..